# hyperref and beamer: Meta Data | 'pdftitle' not Working

Tags: beamer, hyperref

- I want to generate a `beamer` presentation and I want some meta data in the PDF document.
- I therefore use a basic template but the `pdftitle` tag is not recognized (not shown in the PDF properties, see the German "Titel" in the screenshot).
- This seems simple enough - I am afraid, that I do not see the obvious.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {pdftitle}, % <-- Missing in PDF
    pdfauthor = {pdfauthor},
    pdfsubject = {pdfsubject},
    pdfkeywords = {keyword1 keyword2},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test}
    Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try the `beamer` option `usepdftitle=false`.

Comment: @moewe Awesome. Provide an answer (just the comment) and I accept. My Google-Fu was not good this time :(.

Comment: You could also give a `\title`: `\title{PDFtitle}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default `beamer` tries to figure out the `pdftitle` automatically from the `\title` command (similarly the `pdfauthor` is set from the `\author` command). In the example there is no `\title` and `\author`.

The automatic is implemented in a way that `pdftitle` is always overwritten with the information (or absence of information) from `\title` at `\begin{document}`. If `\title` has not been set at that point, the `pdftitle` will be empty. In particular that means that `\title` needs to be set before `\begin{document}` to have any influence on the metadata. If it is issued later, the metadata does not change. The implementation for `pdfauthor` is slightly different, it is overwritten at the point where `\author` is executed. In particular the `pdfauthor` is not overwritten if there is no `\author` command.

**Option 1** Provide `\title` and `\author` information before `\begin{document}`.

```
\title{pdftitle}
\author{pdfauthor}
% before \begin{document}!
```

**Option 2** Disable the automatic generation of PDF metadata from `\title` and `\author` by setting the class option

```
usepdftitle=false
```

and manage the metadata on your own.

Comment: Addition: If I place `\title{pdftitle}` after `\begin{document}` then the tag is not visible in the PDF properties anymore.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Indeed, the `pdftitle` is set in the command `\beamer@firstminutepatches` at or shortly before `\begin{document}`. If you issue `\title` after `\begin{document}` it is too late. `pdfauthor` is different. It is really set at the moment you execute `\author`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess that is the reason why I failed to solve this by myself. In my real document this is also the case and I did not notice the importance of that until now.

Comment: Could you add this to your answer or am I allowed to do so?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I edited the answer, if something is still unclear, feel free to edit it yourself.